# Can you do RSS feeds on a local server? (PHP)

Tags: php, rss

I am using XAMPP and was wondering if I can code my site to include RSS feeds. Would the codes work and can I test it if I am working on a local server?

I am practicing using the OReily head First PHP/Mysql book and I'm on the chapter on RSS and getting RSS videos from youtube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a RSS feed and test it locally, no problem. In the end it is not different from testing your other pages besides that the URL pointing to the RSS feed does not return HTML but XML.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just test it?
Usually there is no problem with getting RSS
But if there will be one - that will be time to come here to SO with the question

if you want to make your own RSS feed, it's not a big deal too. RSS is the same markup as HTML.

Comment: RSS is not "the same markup as HTML", far from it in fact. RSS is based on XML, and you will need to use an RSS specific schema layout for your feed otherwise it will not be readable by many RSS aggregators.

Comment: @DavidYell ROFL. Most funny comment I've ever seen here on SO. HTML table has it's specific schema layout too. otherwise it will not be readable by any browser. So what? Open your eyes and tell me the technical difference between `<td>Name</td>` and `<item>Name</item>`. Especially from the generator's (PHP) point of view

Comment: Well, the way I read your comment made me think that someone who was learning to create an RSS feed may use HTML tags rather than XML ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a feed, but you have to upload them online, so other people can see and use them.

But it will work similar to online-version on localhost.